# Which version of the FAA's Instrument Procedures Handbook is current?

Tags: faa-regulations

I'm looking for the current release of the FAA's Instrument Procedures Handbook. The [FAA website for the IPH](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/instrument_procedures_handbook/) shows FAA-H-8083-16, but other FAA documentation I've found references FAA-H-8261-1A. I've looked for places to buy the Instrument Procedures Handbook such as Amazon and found that they're offering FAA-H-8261-1A.

Which one is current?

For future reference, how do I found the most recent release of an FAA publication?

Comment: From the preface to FAA-H-8083-16, dated 2014: "This handbook supersedes FAA-H-8261-1A, Instrument Procedures Handbook, dated 2007". So as of this writing, the former appears current.

Comment: always on the website. 16 is current, as of last year, but note there are already addenda and errata for the IFH, the last from Apr 2015. Also the IPH was updated last year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

8083-16 ,dated 2014, is current version, superseded 8261-1A. It is stated in [Summary of Change](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/handbooks_manuals/aviation/instrument_procedures_handbook/media/Summary_of_Changes.pdf).

For future reference, the FAA page you linked in the question is best resource available.